# Add a new instance of a class to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and I'm building a card game(seems to be very common and good for beginners).
I have a class called `Cartas`  with a method called `imprimir()` to print a random card.
Then I have a function called `create_deck()` that fills an empty list with 52 cards.

```
import random

class Cards:
    def __init__(self, Value = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]), 
                       Suit = random.choice(["Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades"])):
        self.Value = Value
        self.Suit = Suit

    def imprimir(self):
        if self.Value == 11:
            print("J of " + self.Suit)
        elif self.Value == 12:
            print("Queen of " + self.Suit)
        elif self.Value == 13:
            print("King of " + self.Suit)
        else:
            print(str(self.Value) + " de " + self.Suit)


card = Cards()
card.imprimir()

def create_deck():
    list_deck = []
    list_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    lista_suit = ["Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades"]
    for number in list_numbers:
        for suit in list_suit :
            if card == 11:
                card = f'J of {suit}'
                list_deck.append(card)
            elif number == 12:
                card = f'Queen of {suit}'
                list_deck.append(card)
            elif number == 13:
                card = f'King of {suit}'
                list_deck.append(card)
            else:
                card = f'{number} of {suit}'
                list_deck.append(card)
    print(list_deck)

print(create_deck())
```

I want `create_deck()` to fill the empty list with new instances of `Cards()` instead of filling it with just strings, something like:
`[card1, card2, card3, etc etc,..card52]`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: FYI, your defaults for `__init__` aren't going to work; default arguments are computed and bound at definition time, so for any given run of your program, you'd have precisely one set of defaults for `Card`, e.g. two of hearts every time on the first run, ace of spades every time on the second run, etc. If you want random defaults on each construction, you'll need to define the default as `None` and test for it, replacing with a random choice when it's `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the for-loop you can use list comprehension to do it in one line:

```
list_deck = [Cards(num, suit) for num in list_numbers for suit in list_suit]
```

if you prefer to use the for-loop as you did, then just use your class for adding items to the list:

```
for number in list_numbers:
    for suit in list_suit :
        list_deck.append(Cards(number, suit))
```

if you want to print your Cards objects, then you need to implement **repr** function for your class.

```
def __repr__(self):
    if self.Value == 11:
        return("J of " + self.Suit)
    elif self.Value == 12:
        return("Queen of " + self.Suit)
    elif self.Value == 13:
        return("King of " + self.Suit)
    else:
        return(str(self.Value) + " de " + self.Suit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate it like this:

```py
cards = [Cards() for card in range(n_cards)]
```

with that, for every element in the iterable `range(n_cards)` (which is nothing but a range from 0 to exclusive n_cards (0, 1, 2... n_cards - 1)) you'll add a new `Cards()` object to the list.